# SiftDown Algorithm Number of Comparisons

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, correctness, computer-science-theory

I was recently working with the `siftDown` algorithm used for building binary heaps. In the book "Algorithms and Data Structures: The Basic Toolbox" in exercise 6.5 it is stated that the given implementation of that algorithm needs `2*log(n)` element comparisons. Now, I've tried to figure out why this is so, but I couldn't. Why is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

When calling `siftDown(i)` you first perform two element comparisons:

- The first is between `h[2i]` and `h[2i+1]`.
- The second is between `h[i]` and `h[m]`.

After making the two comparisons you recursively call `siftDown(m)` where `m=2i` or `m=2i+1`. That is, each call to `siftDown()` with an `n`-element heap results in making two element comparisons and a call to `siftDown()` with an `n/2`-element heap.

Therefore, `T(n)`, the number of comparisons made when calling `siftDown()` with an `n`-element heap, satisfies:

```
T(n) = 2 + T(n/2)
```

The solution to this recurrence relation is

```
T(n) = 2logn
```

You can see that the above relation solves to `2logn` by observing that each time, exactly 2 element comparisons are being made, and that the number of times is `logn` (because if you start with `n` and keep dividing by 2 over and over, you're done after `logn` divisions).

Hence, the total number of element comparisons made by `siftDown()` is about `2logn`.